How to compute the bias of the auto-normalized importance sampling estimator

A preceding post has compared auto-normalized importance sampling with ordinal importance sampling. Beginner readers shall be directed there, but I will remind the readers of just enough elements for understanding the question in this post without thoroughly going over that prior one.

Given a target distribution $P(X)$ (but only the unnormalized mass function $g(X)$ is available, such that $p(x) = \frac{g(x)}{Z}$), a proposal distribution $Q(X)$ and a test function $f: X \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, we can estimate the expectation $\mu = \mathbb{E}_P[f(X)]$ by auto-normalized importance sampling as follows
$$
\hat\mu = 
\frac{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f(x_i)}
{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)},
\ x_i \sim Q(X) \ i.i.d.
$$
where $w(x) = \frac{g(x)}{q(x)}$.
Note that $\hat\mu$ is a biased estimator as the ratio of expectations does not necessarily equal to the expectation of the ratio, though it is consistent.
It is also shown in Agapiou et al. (2014) that the bias is $O(\frac{1}{N})$. I tried to paraphrase the proof on my own and encountered some troubles. I will present the part that I have successfully paraphrased and can anyone help complete the rest? No need to look into the paper in detail.
To show the bias, we need to compute $\mathbb{E}_Q[\hat\mu - \mu]$,
\begin{split}
 \hat\mu - \mu
 & = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f(x_i)}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)} - \mu \\
 & = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) [f(x_i) - \mu]}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)}
\end{split}
Note that
$\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)(f(X)-\mu)] = \sum_{x\in X}\frac{g(x)}{q(x)}(f(x)-\mu)q(x) = Z\mu - Z\mu = 0$. Let $f'(x) = f(x) - \mu$, we have
\begin{split}
 \hat\mu - \mu
 & = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i)}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)} \\
 & = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i) - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)}
\end{split}
Note that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]$, and also, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)$ is an unbiased estimator of $\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)]$, therefore,
$$
\mathbb{E}_Q\Big[\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i) - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)]}\Big] = 0
$$
Now the bias can be written as
\begin{split}
 \mathbb{E}_Q[\hat\mu - \mu]
 & = \mathbb{E}_Q\Big[\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i) - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)}\Big] \\
 & = \mathbb{E}_Q\Big[\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i) - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i)} - \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N w(x_i) f'(x_i) - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)]}\Big]\\
\end{split}
To simplify the notation, we denote $\mu_{mc}(g)$ as the sample mean up to the evaluation function $g$. With a slight abuse of notation, the above equation can be re-written as
\begin{split}
 \mathbb{E}_Q[\hat\mu - \mu]
 & = \mathbb{E}_Q\Big[\frac{\mu_{mc}(wf') - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\mu_{mc}(w)} - \frac{\mu_{mc}(wf') - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)]}{\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)]}\Big] \\
 & = \mathbb{E}_Q\Bigg[ \frac{1}{\mu_{mc}(wf')\cdot \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)]}
 \Big [\mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)] - \mu_{mc}(w) \Big ]
 \Big [\mu_{mc}(wf') - \mathbb{E}_Q[w(X)f'(X)] \Big ] \Bigg ]
\end{split}
I am only able to get this far.
The proof target is to show the above is upper bounded by $\frac{12 \mathbb{E}_Q[g(X)^2]}{N \mathbb{E}_Q[g(X)]^2}$, i.e. $O(\frac{1}{N})$ up to a constant  linear in the second moment.

Several hints of statistical facts that may help complete the proof:

$|\mathbb{E}[f_1(X) + f_2(X)]| \leq |\mathbb{E}[f_1(X)]| + |\mathbb{E}[f_2(X)]|$
The random variable of sample mean follows a normal distribution $\texttt{normal}(\mu, \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}})$
Morkov's inequality: $\mathbb{P}[X \geq a] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{a}$
Chebyshev's inequality: $\mathbb{P}[|X - \mu_X| \geq b] \leq \frac{Var[X]}{b^2}$

References:

A preceding post that compared auto-normalized importance sampling with ordinal importance sampling.
Agapiou et al. (2014), Theorem 2.1 (proof in Section 6.3).
The original paper that proposed weighted importance sampling, where I did not find the proof showing the estimator is unbiased.


@Xi'an: thanks for your reminder, it was actually a typo: there should indeed be an expectation surrounding them all. See my fixed one above
